# Cannot get Python code to catch psycopg2 and Django errors

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I cannot get my code to catch these exceptions:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import IntegrityError, errors
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError as ie
```

...

```
try:
    parent = Code.objects.get(arrow=parrow)
except (Code.DoesNotExist, psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation, IntegrityError, ie):
    logging.warning(f"Parent '{parrow}' of {child} not yet in database.")
    waitroom.append((parrow, child))
```

...

```
   psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "codeAT_code" violates foreign key constraint "codeAT_code_childof_id_78f76bc4_fk_codeAT_code_uniqid"
DETAIL:  Key (childof_id)=(c74d8ad6-f23e-4b63-860f-e80f54b7c4cc) is not present in table "codeAT_code".
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "codeAT_code" violates foreign key constraint "codeAT_code_childof_id_78f76bc4_fk_codeAT_code_uniqid"
DETAIL:  Key (childof_id)=(c74d8ad6-f23e-4b63-860f-e80f54b7c4cc) is not present in table "codeAT_code"
```

...

In addition to nothing being caught, PyCharm does not recognize psycopg2's ForeignKeyViolation, saying it is an unresolved reference. I've tried stating it many different ways. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Quick hack: `except (Exception) as e` and print/log the `type(e)`. Just to make sure it is one of the exceptions you listed.